# How do I build a aws cloud monitoring which alerts when any new resource (ec2 or rds or s3) is launched

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

We have individual teams that are launching ec2/rds/s3 instances and they are not choosing right instances or leaving instances running for long time, so how do I build a simple alert system that tells me what was launched?

I am trying to looking into building something on top of cloudwatch but I have to use SNS to do it. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Read about [AWS Config](https://aws.amazon.com/config/) and [AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/index.html) and [understand the differences](https://www.sumologic.com/blog/aws-config-vs-cloudtrail/).

Comment: If the appropriate metrics are available in Amazon CloudWatch, then yes -- you can uses Amazon SNS to send notifications via email, SMS, etc. However, if you want to check instance types or identify 'long-running' instances, then you'll need extra code. For example: [Simple EC2 Stopinator in Lambda - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/simple-ec2-stopinator-in-lambda-5goj)

Answer (score 1):

By utilizing the SNS alerts, AWS users can receive notifications whenever new resources are created within their accounts.Here is the architecture diagram for the solution.
[New resources alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGmu5.png)

To get an email alert whenever a new resource is created in your AWS account, you can setup an EventBridge rule with SNS topic as target.

First enable the AWS Config that records the creation of new resources in your account.
Create an Eventbridge rule with an event pattern that discovers when new resources are created in the account.

Here is a sample for S3 bucket and you can edit the resource type then add your required resource:

```
{
  "detail": {
    "configurationItem": {
      "configurationItemStatus": ["ResourceDiscovered"],
      "resourceType": ["AWS::S3::Bucket"]
    },
    "messageType": ["ConfigurationItemChangeNotification"]
  },
  "detail-type": ["Config Configuration Item Change"],
  "source": ["aws.config"]
}
```

Add the SNS topic with email subscription as target to the eventbridge rule and configure the  Input transformer for customized alert email.

[This is how the email alert looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qow6j.png)

For more information, check this:

https://medium.com/@TechStoryLines/receive-sns-alerts-when-new-resources-are-created-in-your-aws-account-db749b16445f

https://techstorylines.hashnode.dev/receive-sns-alerts-when-new-resources-are-created-in-your-aws-account

Answer (score 0):

*they are not choosing right instances or leaving instances running for long time*

- You can simply introduce an IAM policy that will restrict the instance launch with specific Instance types
- Long-running Servers: you can make use of CW metrics and take necessary action

For RDS, S3 and other resources, I would recommend AWS Config so that you can keep track of all of your resources.